# ROSSerial Msg.h equivalent in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is their a equivalent in the main ROS structure for the Msg.h contained in rosserial. I have need for the ability to use a single call to serialize and serialize a range of different message types. Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252332/rosserial-msg.h-equivalent-in-ros/) by [inkspell4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28072/inkspell4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're not using Python, I believe the only way to do that would be to use the [ShapeShifter](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/topic_tools/html/classtopic__tools_1_1ShapeShifter.html) (and perhaps in combination with [facontidavide/ros_type_introspection](https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_type_introspection)).

For `ShapeShifter` there are some good posts on this board on how to use it / find references. It's not really documented, as it's not really meant as a public API.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inkspell4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28072/inkspell4/) on 2017-01-19**:
what is the shapeshifter meant to do, from what I could tell it looks to be a type of publisher?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:
As far as I can tell it would seem to allow you to do exactly what you asked for: use a single subscriber to subscribe to multiple topics, each of a different type.

**Comment by [inkspell4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28072/inkspell4/) on 2017-01-22**:
What function would be used for subscribing? All I can see is advertise which would create a publisher.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-22**:
The `ros_type_introspection` has some [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection/Tutorials) that will probably help you.

The answer to #q50375 also contains some hints.

**Comment by [inkspell4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28072/inkspell4/) on 2017-01-22**:
Ok, I was looking at the class in the wrong way that is exactly what I need. Thank you.